# Pytrends timezone (tz)

Tags: python, timezone, google-trends

I´m strugeling a bit with Pytrends, specifically the TZ. When changing the timezones, it does not change the timestamp in the output.

```
    pytrends = TrendReq(hl = 'en-US', tz = 120)
keywords = ['lei', 'lei code', 'legal entity identifier']

data = pytrends.get_historical_interest(keywords, year_start=2021, month_start=5, day_start=30,
 hour_start=0, year_end=2021, month_end=6, day_end=1, 
hour_end=0, geo='IE', gprop='', sleep=0)
data
```

Output:

```python
date lei    lei code    legal entity identifier isPartial               
2021-05-31 07:00:00 54  0   0   False

2021-05-31 08:00:00 44  13  0   False

2021-05-31 09:00:00 33  0   0   False

2021-05-31 10:00:00 74  0   0   True
```

If I then change the timezone (tz) the output is the same

```
        pytrends = TrendReq(hl = 'en-US', tz = 0)
    keywords = ['lei', 'lei code', 'legal entity identifier']
    
    data = pytrends.get_historical_interest(keywords, year_start=2021, month_start=5, day_start=30,
     hour_start=0, year_end=2021, month_end=6, day_end=1, 
    hour_end=0, geo='IE', gprop='', sleep=0)
    data
```

Output:

```python
date lei lei code legal entity identifier isPartial


2021-05-31 07:00:00 54  0   0   False

2021-05-31 08:00:00 44  13  0   False

2021-05-31 09:00:00 33  0   0   False

2021-05-31 10:00:00 74  0   0   True
```

Probably something obvious I'm missing but how can I make the times change with the timezones.
Was thinking about just lagging the output after.

With regards K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is returning the results in UTC format, You can use this code as an alternative to convert UTC to other timezone(For ex. EST )

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pytz

pytrends = TrendReq(hl = 'en-US', tz = 200)
keywords = ['lei', 'lei code', 'legal entity identifier']

data = pytrends.get_historical_interest(keywords, year_start=2021, month_start=5, day_start=30,
 hour_start=0, year_end=2021, month_end=6, day_end=1, 
hour_end=0, geo='IE', gprop='', sleep=0)

index = data.index
data.index = index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(pytz.timezone('EST')).tz_localize(None)
data
```

You can get list of timezones using this

```
pytz.all_timezones
```

Hope so this would solve your problem