# Google Trends scraper Python timezones

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-trends

I'm currently working on a Python google trends scraper and I'm trying to figure out how they calculate their numbers for the tz parameters. I'm Pacific Time and it gives me tz=420 in the network tab of inspect elements. How can I calculate what the east coast would be? I tried using my VPN to refresh the page from New York, but it still gave me a tz=420.

Thank you

Comment: You could use `datetime.now(tz=None)` if you want real timezone conversion but what you have is a GMT offset not a full timezone specification. You'd be better off using timezone agnostic timestamps fot transport in the fututre.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67903148/11878472, check this solution